# Don't know why my child process is reading EOF from pipe

Tags: c, process, fork, pipe

So I'm writing a program right now that runs three processes as such: parse->sort->suppress.  'Parse' is the parent of 'sort' and 'sort' is the parent of 'suppress'.  I do not know the code for sort.  All I know is that it uses standard I/O file descriptors.  For some reason 'Suppress' always gets an EOF char and thus never ending my program without sort processing the data it's supposed to get before it receives an EOF char.

Avoiding my program's inner workings (commented out) here is how is how I set up the pipes.

**Is there a reason my pipe from 'sort' to 'suppress' is sending an EOF prematurely due to the pipe setup?**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int status1;
int ps_id[2];
//setup parse->sort pipe
if (pipe(ps_id) == -1)
{
    perror("ps pipe: ");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
//sort&suppress
if (!fork())
{
    int status2;
    int ss_id[2];
    //setup sort->suppress pipe
    if (pipe(ss_id) == -1)
    {
        perror("ss pipe: ");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    //suppress
    if (!fork())
    {
        close(ps_id[0]);
        close(ps_id[1]);
        close(ss_id[1]);
        //do stuff
        close(ss_id[0]);
    }
    //suppress
    else
    {
        close(ps_id[1]);
        close(ss_id[0]);
        dup2(ps_id[0], 0);
        dup2(ss_id[1], 1);
        close(ps_id[0]);
        close(ss_id[1]);
        excel("/bin/sort", "sort", (char*)0);
        wait(&status2);
    }
}
//parse
else
{
    close(ps_id[0]);
    //do stuff
    close(ps_id[1]);
    wait(&status1);
}
}
```

Comment: Guess I missing it: Where is the EOF?